# how to access with Linux to the real block size info of a filesystem when it is mounted on nfs?

Tags: filesystems, nfs

I have a Centos 6.5 and Solaris 5 machines. I'm trying to get the information about block size of a filesystem in the member f_frsize of statvfs. 
I tried first from Centos but when the filesystem is mounted in nfs, i got a value like 32768 or 65536. I think this value is the nfs data block size and not the block size.

And when i try to get the block size info of the same nfs filesystem but from Sun Solaris, i get a value like 1024.

So why did i get a different block size (f_frsize) when calling statvfs from Solaris and from Linux ?

Is there a way to get the f_frsize info of the nfs filesystem and not this nfs data block size ?
i don't know if what i want is possible, but i would like more informations about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my problem.
It is simply a problem of mathematics !
Different numbers can give the same result.
So between Linux and Solaris, the member f_frsize has a different value. But it doesn't matter because when you convert blocks to bytes using the f_frsize in both OS with this formula taken from [here](http://svn.fonosfera.org/fon-ng/trunk/luci/libs/luanet/src/df.c):

```
static unsigned long kscale(unsigned long b, unsigned long bs)
{
     return (b * (unsigned long long) bs + 1024/2) / 1024;
}
```

I got the same result as with the df command and in both OS.
So there is no real problem, just my imagination :) Sorry.